# After connecting to a server using ftps://somesite.com the files cannot be dragged and dropped there?

Tags: macos, finder, ftp

I just learned of a new way to connect to a server and do secure `ftp`, which is to use Finder, and use `Go -> Connect to Server` and use

```
ftps://xyz.somesite.com
```

and it will open the directories just like inside of Finder (although on Mavericks, it is an X-window type of window. On Sierra, it looks like a native window). However, I found that I can drag and drop files from the remote server to the local hard drive, but not the other way around.  Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) != secure FTP. But anyway, do you have write access to that server? Can you copy the files there from command line `sftp`?

Comment: first, `sftp` is secure, right? Are you saying `ftps` is not secure? By the way, yes, I can `sftp` to that site with password and upload / download, but not with `ftps://xyz.somesite.com`

Comment: The point was just in the terms and tags. You have `sftp` tag and you talk about `ftps` which is something different. FTPS should be secure. And you should be able to connect with `ftp` command line tool (if that is in Apple).

Comment: that's because as of right now, I cannot add or create a tag `ftps`, and I submitted to meta already